# MATLAB "any" conditional deletion translation to Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm having trouble understanding what `B = A(~any(A < threshold, 2), :);` (in MATLAB) does given array `A` with dimensions N x 3.

Ultimately, I am trying to implement a function do perform the same operation in Python (so far, I have something like `B = A[not any(A[:,1] < threshold), :]`, which I know to be incorrect), and I was wondering what the numpy equivalent to such an operation would be.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not much of difference really. In MATLAB, you are performing `ANY` along the rows with `any(...,2)`. In NumPy, you have `axis` to denote those dimensions and for a `2D` array, it would be `np.any(...,axis=1)`.

Thus, the NumPy equivalent implementation would be -

```
import numpy as np

B = A[~np.any(A < threshold,axis=1),:]
```

This indexing is also termed as [`slicing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) in NumPy terminology. Since, we are slicing along the first axis, we can drop the all-elements-selection along the rest of the axes. So, it would simplify to -

```
B = A[~np.any(A < threshold,axis=1)]
```

Finally, we can use the method [`ndarray.any`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.any.html) and skip the mention of `axis` parameter to shorten the code further, like so -

```
B = A[~(A < threshold).any(1)]
```